# web3 and Pyinstaller. No package metadata was found for eth-typing

Tags: python, pyinstaller, metadata, exe, web3py

I used web3.py to create my program. Code works good. I turned it into exe with PyInstaller, but I`m getting this error, when I try to launch the exe.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "web3\init.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_account\init.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_account\account.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_keyfile\init.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_keyfile\keyfile.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_keys\init.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_keys\main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_utils\init.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_utils\abi.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_utils\crypto.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_utils\conversions.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "eth_typing\init.py", line 75, in <module>
  File "importlib\metadata\init.py", line 1008, in version
  File "importlib\metadata\init.py", line 981, in distribution
  File "importlib\metadata\init.py", line 565, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for eth-typing
```

I try to install different version of web3, but it still doesn`t work. Help please)

Comment: What is the point of trying a different version? The error says that package metadata was not found. Try adding a manifest or setup.cfg file described at https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html